# How to resolve error with 7zip not getting installed using chef-client version 14.6.47

Tags: chef-infra, 7zip, cookbook

I am getting below error

```
Recipe: 7zip::default[0m
amazon-ebs:   * windows_zipfile[c:/dirname/] action unzip
amazon-ebs:     [0m
amazon-ebs:     ================================================================================[0m
amazon-ebs:     [31mError executing action `unzip` on resource 'windows_zipfile[c:/dirname/]'[0m
amazon-ebs:     ================================================================================[0m
amazon-ebs:
amazon-ebs: [0m    NameError[0m
amazon-ebs:     ---------[0m
amazon-ebs:     undefined local variable or method `source' for #<#<Class:0x0000000003f01f60>:0x0000000006da13c0>[0m
```

and below is my code related 7zip cookbook recipe.

```rb
windows_zipfile 'c:/dirname/' do
  source "#{node[:packages][:ziputil]}"
  action :unzip
  not_if {::File.exists?('c:/dirname/7za.exe')}
end
```

and source URI is: `http://downloads.sourceforge.net/sevenzip/7za920.zip`

I have tried updating the the chef-client version to versions like 14.2.0 & 15.1.36 but that didn't helped?

Can someone please suggest? Do we need to update something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `windows_zipfile` resource seems to come from the [windows](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/windows) cookbook from Supermarket. This seems to be deprecated. Since you are now on chef-client > 15, you can use [archive_file](https://docs.chef.io/resources/archive_file/) resource. Something like below should work:

```rb
remote_file 'C:/Users/Public/7za920.zip' do
  source 'http://downloads.sourceforge.net/sevenzip/7za920.zip'
  action :create
end

archive_file 'C:/Users/Public/7za920.zip' do
  destination 'C:/Users/Public/7zip'
  action :extract
end
```

You can replace the path and attributes as per your requirement.

There is also a [windows_package](https://docs.chef.io/resources/windows_package/) resource which can directly install an MSI, which can be downloaded from https://www.7-zip.org/download.html.